# How can I update Microsoft Teams Invitation Text for Teams message?

Tags: powershell, office-365, administration, microsoft-teams

Whenever we schedule any teams meeting, the meeting invite has following format:

[image]

But what I want is below format:

[image]

I want to remove the extra text that are not useful.

How can I remove those additional texts?

Note: I have tried "Meeting setting" under "Meeting" in Teams admin center and it is not helpful. It just allow me to add some additional text into it.

Is there any way using which I can update the existing meeting invite text in MS Teams?

Comment: Hi @Aakash, does below answer help you?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I am still figuring out the alternatives on this. Once I am confirmed I will come back here

Comment: @GaneshSanap I got an feedback from one of my client that in GCC High environment they have did this kind of configurations. But do not have permission to view in GCC high. Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to any GCC High environment to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using meeting settings in Teams, you can only add organization logo, specific URLs and custom footers below default meeting invite text.

**Documentation**: [Customize MS teams meeting invitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/meeting-settings-in-teams#customize-your-meeting-invitations)

You cannot fully customize the default meeting invite text from Teams admin center/Microsoft Teams.

However, if you are scheduling meeting from Outlook, you can customize the meeting invite text manually each time you schedule the meeting.

1. Go to outlook
2. Click on +New Email dropdown and select **Meeting**

   [image]
3. Click on "Teams Meeting" option at the top. It will add default meeting invite text in email/invitation body. You can then customize the invitation as per your requirements.

   [image]

---

At this point you would need to manually edit that text every time a meeting invite has been created. There is no workaround that.

So, if you are scheduling meetings from Microsoft Teams, you can edit your meeting after the meeting invite has been sent out and make required changes manually.

However, I would suggest you to submit a feedback/idea on [Microsoft Teams feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) and Microsoft may take a look at implementing your idea.

**Source**: [Teams Meeting settings - Change the Teams Meeting invitation text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/924759/teams-meeting-settings-change-the-teams-meeting-in.html)